# C# Formatting a string with string.Format("00-00-00")

Tags: c#

I am attempting convert this string "123456" to "12-34-56".
I try to use this code but it doesn't seem to work correctly

```
string.Format("00-00-00", "123456");
```

Can anyone help me find a suitable pattern? Thanks for any help

Comment: First, you pass the format string "123456" which does not contain any "{0}". Look up string.Format documentation. Second, there are no custom string formats. If "123456" were an integer, not a string, you can use `string.Format("{0:00'-'00'-'00}", 123456);` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1fCXHG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below

```
string.Format("{0:##-##-##}", 123456);
```

If number is represented as string the convert to int

```
string.Format("{0:##-##-##}", Convert.ToInt32("123456"));
```

The above will print the output as

> 12-34-56

Answer (score 3):

Your format string is not correct, composite formatted string should be enclosed within curly braces and can have three parameters as follows,

**{ index[,alignment][:formatString] }**

While alignment and formatString are optional, index is mandatory.

In your case, it is a single string "123456" with index 0 which is to be formatted in the following pattern "12-34-56".

So, we use the index and format string to achieve the desired output.

To represent a digit 0-9 (optional) in the format string, we use the placeholder '#'.

'#' holds 0, if there exists no digit corresponding to the position in the object, else it replaces the 0 with the digit in place.

The following format string would be suitable for your need,

**##-##-##** -> three numbers with 2 digits each separated by a hyphen.

Now, putting that in place using the composite format syntax,
**"{0:##-##-##}"**

Usage:

String input:

```
var s = "123456";
Console.WriteLine("{0:##-##-##}", Convert.ToInt32(s));
```

Integer input:

```
var n = 123456;
Console.WriteLine("{0:##-##-##}", n);
```